# Add no-objc-arc to the implementation or interface file

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class (NDTrie on github) which uses c struct for its internal structure, it would make it easier for users to use it in their projects with automatic reference counting by adding the fno-objc-arc to the source file instead of requiring users to set it in the build phase for that source file, is there a way to do that.

Comment: Maybe. Now ask a question.

Comment: Also, it's `fno-objc-arc`.  **F** for flag.

Comment: @CodaFi `f` for feature. Similarly, `-marc arm`, etc. Here, `m` stands for machine. Look it up in the clang docs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Per-file compiler flags are tacked onto files on a per-project basis (files meant to be compiled down to some form of machine code generally try to avoid metadata).  If you'd like to specify the flag and have it update the required field in any Xcode project, you can use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) to write a pod file for your dependancy.  Let the underlying tool handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to separate *portions of translations* based on features and alter their flags for that translation in this case.

You should approach it from another angle. The ARC feature treats all preprocessed input as having ARC enabled or not, based on the compiler flags of the current translation.

The most obvious workarounds:

0) Impact reduction: Hide the implementation, where possible

1) Translation specific conditions: Use `__has_feature(objc_arc)` to determine whether you are or are not dealing with an ARC-enabled translation -- if you are using clang, the expression `__has_feature(objc_arc)` expands to 1 when ARC is enabled. Then you can conditionally make portions of your program visible or annotate it differently, depending on whether or not ARC is enabled.

2) Detect and fail: In some remaining cases, you may opt for:

```
// >> detect clang or GCC if needed
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This file cannot be compiled with ARC enabled (+HYPERLINK so you don't get a flooded inbox)
#endif
// << detect clang or GCC if needed
```